# Is there a Checkstyle Formatter Maven plugin to format according to custom Checkstyle rules?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

Is there a Maven plugin to format source code according to a custom Checkstyle configuration?

I would like to know if there is something similar to Spotless `mvn spotless:apply` command but for Checkstyle (without relying on an IDE plugin).

Comment: spotless has a maven plugin.  groupId: com.diffplug.spotless, spotless-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm asking for Checkstyle not Spotless

Comment: If you are asking for auto fix capabilities, there is no such plugin, there is maven checkstyle plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/